# How to get date in dd-mm-yyyy format

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, date

I am building a web application which requires date to be entered, but
 on entering a date it will be saved in mm-dd-yyyy and on using
 bootstrap it will be saved in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Below is the code.

```
searchTrain(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.trains(this.state)
    this.setState({ to: '', from: '', date: '' })
  }

  onChangeTrain(e) {
    this.setState(
      { [e.target.id]: e.target.value }
      //   , () => console.log(this.state)
    );
  }

 <div className="col" >
            <label >
              <span>Journey Date <span className="required">*</span></span>
              <input type="date" className="input-field" id="date"
                value={this.state.date} onChange={this.onChangeTrain} 

                />
            </label>
          </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using moment? https://momentjs.com/

Comment: I want it in dd-mm-yyyy format

Comment: Storing the date in a non-standard format is a bad idea. Store it as ISO instead.

Comment: I am using for this api.     https://api.railwayapi.com/v2/cancelled/date/<dd-mm-yyyy>/apikey/<apikey>/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
const today = Date.now();

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('pt-BR', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit',
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  second: '2-digit'
}).format(today));
```

Comment: its the date selected from input box. Not the current date

Comment: @AbhishekKonnur then substitute it in `const today`, what's the matter?

Comment: Anyway, Marcelo, close but it shouldn't include the time. Also, why `pt-BR` specifically?

Comment: Okay will check with your approach.

Comment: Sorry, to not include the time: const today = Date.now();

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('pt-BR', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit'
}).format(today));

Comment: The format "DD/MM/YYYY" is used here in Brazil. That why i use "pt-BR"

Answer (score 0):

convert both dates before saving,
Use momentJS

```
moment("05-05-2012", 'mm-dd-yyyy').format('dd-mm-yyyy');
```

Answer (score -1):

Using moment will be a plug and play thing
include

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/en-ca.js"></script>

var date = moment('30-06-2010', 'DD-MM-YYYY')

date.format('MM-DD-YYYY')
```